# read part of webpage html in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webrequest

Suppose that we have a very large Html page.
I want read part of this html in a timeout(until my time out finish)

I using this code for obtain html :

```
  Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
  request.Timeout = 1 * 1000
  request.ContentType = "text/html"
  Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
      Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)
             html = reader.ReadToEnd()
      End Using
  End Using
```

In this code when timeout finished,one exeption occured and I can not get any part of the html.

how I can do it? please help me.

Comment: What was the exception?

Comment: exepion is :"The operation has timed out " ___ it accour in his line:"Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()"

Comment: I also need to know how to do this